# Can't figure out what is wrong with my .htaccess RewriteRule statement

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permalinks

I've got no idea how to properly use the `.htaccess` file and all the guides and tutorials out there aren't the easiest to understand.

Here is my current code...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ productpage.php?productidpage=$1&brand=$2&productname=$3 [L,NC]
```

I want it to display as `www.mysite.com/$1/$2/$3/` whenever `productpage.php` is loaded.

Well, actually I want it to display as `www.mysite.com/$2/$3` if that's possible.

The `productidpage` variable is what is picked up in the code to load the page, `$2` and `$3` are purely there just to modify the URL.

Comment: See [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading slash in your regular expression. The leading slash in URI's are removed when matching the `RewriteRule`'s expression when rules are in htaccess files.

```
# no slash---v maybe a slash here---v
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ productpage.php?productidpage=$1&brand=$2&productname=$3 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I removed the slash but it still didn't do anything.

Comment: @user1576895 oh, you're also missing the slash at the end of the expression (right before the `$`).

Comment: grrr I put the slash in, no effect. It's just doing nothing, not even throwing out an error. But if I deliberately type crap in there it does throw out an error.

Comment: @user1576895 Are these the only rules in the htaccess file? Is this htaccess file in your document root? Does adding a slash in front of `productpage.php` help?

Comment: no the slash in front of productpage didn't have any effect. I am using hostgator as my host. It's not my main domain, that has a wordpress install on it. This is another domain which I added and assigned a folder for that domains root dir. The .htaccess file is in there. I've also made a test.mysite.com subdomain which I am testing all this on, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @user1576895, your regexp will _never_ match with a leading / in an `.htaccess` context.  It will match if you've constructed it correctly without it.  Read the debugging tips Q&A that I pointed you at above.  You also need to specify the correct `RewriteBase` in your subdomain `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `AllowOverride FileInfo` or (`AllowOverride All`) is set for the `<Directory>` containing your `.htaccess` files.

Then set `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` *at the server or virtual host level* to debug your rewrite rules.

**Update:** I highly recommend you to check out [Ask Apache](http://www.askapache.com) - it has tons of `mod_rewrite` info and examples.

Comment: ^ Ok, where does all this have to go, in the .htaccess or the actual server settings. I am going into un charted territory here.

Comment: `AllowOverride` is recognized in global server settings, inside `<VirtualHost>` and inside `<Directory>`. Rewrite logging can only be enabled for the entire server or for a specific virtual host.